# Membership operator in same reference

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does `x in x` in this snippet produce false?

```
x = [1,2,3,8,9,12]
print(x in x)
```

Gives me the output:
`False`

Shouldn't this give me true?

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking about `x` as if it were a `set`? Try `x = {1, 2, 3}`. Then `print(x.issubset(x))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You checking if `x` which is a list of numbers, is inside of it self.
you can clearly say its wrong, cause the list does not contain itself.

You can think on it as it is a box, the box contains values, in this case some numbers, 1,2,3,8,9,12, when you using the keyword `in` you asking if something is inside the box, and as you can see, there is no box in the box, because there is only numbers here, only 1,2,3,8,9,12 inside the box right now.

the box is big place, which can store whatever you want it to store, even other boxes, for example:

```py
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
x.append(y)
print(y in x) # True
```

it can store whatever you want, but if it's not inside the box, the statement `in` will be false

incase you interested in reading more about how does it work, you can read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) section about it (most likely you interested in `__contains__`

If you want this to be true you can do `x.append(x)` and then gets true for it

Comment: Can you elaborate on "the list does not contain itself"? What does it contain?

Comment: @user10728141 the list contain the values 1,2,3,8,9,12, when you using the key word ```in``` you are asking if the list ```x``` is one of the values inside ```x```, which is false

Comment: So it does contain itself? If not, what else does it contain?

Comment: @user10728141 i added some explantion the the answer, about how you can think about it

Comment: Ok, what really helped me clear things out was when you said **there is no box inside the box**. And then you proceeded to explain that if you want the _actual box_ inside the box then just append the box itself as an object inside the box.

Comment: yes, that what i said :) happy to  help :), Metaphors is a good way to explain those things